# How to determine if an object was 'first' or 'created'?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have refactored some code in a long running rake task. I used to have this code:

```
if object = Object.find_by_name(name: "string")
else
  object = Object.create(name: "string")
  puts "#{object.name} created"
end
```

Now I have this code:

```
object = Object.where(name: "string").first_or_create
```

I figure this is an improvement.  But, I am really missing the puts statement in the long running rake task.  How can I determine if the object was 'first' or 'created' when using first_or_create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on top of @xdazz's answer, [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) has

```
obj = Model.find_or_create_by_name("String")
obj.persisted? #=> false
obj.save
obj = Model.find_or_create_by_name("String")
obj.persisted? #=> true
```

This method does the same thing you're doing.

Comment: This did not work for me, but it opened my eyes to find_or_initialize_by which works.  Question: is this code better than my original code above?  Now I have find_or_initialize_by followed by an if statement on obj.persisted? and if false, then object.save and puts "#{object.name} saved".  Not much different than my original code.

Comment: The code is perhaps not better. If your code is better at achieving your goal then you should keep using it. The `find_or_*_by_*` methods are, however, known by everyone who has experience with Rails. A new member on your team should already know what it does, whereas they may not know what `first_or_create` means.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 
`object .persisted?`  or `object .new_record?` to check it.

`object .persisted?` returns true if the object is already in db,

`object.new_record?` returns true if the object is newly created.